# VSCode Keyboard shortcut option + shift + f and option + z not working, printing special characters on macos catalina

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, macos-catalina

Some vscode shortcuts involving the option key not working in vscode, instead printing special characters.

```
control + shift + f

control + z
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Figured out the solution to the problem, the issue was with input sources, The selected input source was "ABC - India", removed it and added "ABC"

[Image of the keyboard input sources settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuiNv.png)

Comment: i had similar problem with "option + z" (word wrap) and is resolved with this solution

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful solution, I was struggling since months.

Comment: bro this kept me blocked for hours, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

(1) open `keyboard-shortcut` to see if you have conflicts by searching the keys.
(2) open `keyboard-binding.json` to see if you redefined some shortcuts.
(3) close vscode, and find whether these shortcuts are redefined in other programs.

Comment: Checked all of the above, the issue was with the input sources, I found the solution and posted it as an answer. Thanks for your help regardless @insight